# Button arredondado tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, button, tkinter, widget

Existe alguma maneira de arredondar as pontas do button? Ou ate mesmo deixar ele como uma circunferência?

Como esse por exemplo:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Com tkinter tenho quase certeza que não, ele é muito simplesinho apenas para coisinhas visuais, tente outra biblioteca para isso. Recomendo fortemente usar kivy para GUI de maneira profissional. O tkinter só serve para a gente parar de olhar pro console um pouco, mas continua mesma coisa basicamente.

Comment: O desenvolvimento em kivy é muito diferente do tkinter? Sem ser a parte dele ser mais completo, digo a codificação?

Comment: E vc indica algum curso de Kivy?

Comment: Curso não vou saber te falar, mas a galera do python br já ta adotando. O esquema dele é um pouco diferente mas a kivylang(uma linguagem própria dele) é bem tranquilinha de aprender. Dá uma olhada, porque usar tkinter para algo "profissional" ou comercial é ruim, é tipo usar winforms em C# manja? O kivy tem a vantagem que da pra você fazer até app de smartphone ainda, multiplataforma.

Comment: Eu encontrei um completaço, o cara que ministra é do eXscript fica aqui o link pra que chegar nesse post:  https://www.udemy.com/curso-de-python-android-ios-windows-linux-mac/

Comment: Po, dahora. Eu fiz umas coisas em kivy e achei legal, aparentemente tem tudo para começar ser o futuro de app com python, o cada da eXscript é bom, vou colocar na listinha pro futuro também.

Answer (score 3):

Muito fácil, é só criar a imagem do botão redondo nesses sites que criam botões no formato png, dai vc cria uma instância da sua imagem `botao_redondo.png` numa variável, tipo:

```
self.imgRedondo = PhotoImage(file='\\caminho\\botao_redondo.png')
```

em seguida:

```
self.btnRedondo = Button(pai,image=self.imgRedondo,bd=0,relief=GROOVE,bg='A cor de fundo do pai do botão para que o canto do botão não apareça, fincando só a imagem do botão')
```

E por fim, empacota o botão.

Answer (score 0):

depende, você cria 3 imagens, por exemplo, um botão de fechar "X", uma imagem para quando o mouse não tiver em cima dele, e quando o mouse tiver em cima, e quando ele for clicado, depois só definir o relief FLAT para todos.